# Regular expression for moving file

Tags: shell

I have this code in shell script. What it does is that it removes all extensions including dots (.) in a file name and returns just the name, like so `/home/user/filename`. But the problem is that I want it to remove even the directory structure and return just the file name like this `filename`.

Here's the code that removes only the extension.

```
filename="/home/user/filename.php.txt.doc"      
newname=${filename%%.*}
echo $newname
/home/user/filename
```

Is there a way of getting just the file name and not with the directory extension included?

```
filename
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `"${filename##*/}"` to get the name of the file.

```
$ filename="/home/user/filename.php.txt.doc"      
$ newname=${filename%%.*}
$ newname=${newname##*/}
$ echo $newname
filename
```

Alternatively, use `basename`:

```
$ filename="/home/user/filename.php.txt.doc"      
$ newname="$(basename ${filename%%.*})"
$ echo $newname
```

You can also do it with a single sed command, but it is a bit unreadable, so I wouldn't:

```
$ sed 's|.*/\([^\.]*\).*|\1|g' <<< "$filename"
filename
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code did the trick big time. Thanks also to the other guys for the contributions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to get the last field `filename` with field separator as `/`:

```
newname=$(echo "$newname" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}')
```

Adding this line to your code:

```
filename="/home/user/filename.php.txt.doc"      
newname=${filename%%.*}
newname=$(echo "$newname" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}')
echo $namename
```

Output:

```
filename
```

Comment: Ugh. Why a fork to awk when it can be done in just the shell?

Comment: And don't `echo`. Use a herestring instead.

Comment: Just offering a shell script beginner's perspective =) but I am looking at the other solutions now and learning new things!

Comment: @dogbane: I'm confused about herestrings even after a bit of googling: is it just using the `<<<` syntax over `echo`? (As in: `awk '{print $0}' <<< $stuff`?)

Comment: @sampson-chen  Yes, in your answer you can use: `awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' <<< "$newname"`

Answer (score 0):

```
newname=$(basename "$filename")
newname=${newname%%.*}
echo $newname
filename
```